# Flip divs using a function

Tags: javascript, function

I'm new with javascript and I have a tiny problem.

I want to create a function and by pressing that button to invert the two divs ( the first one to be placed second and viceversa). I hope you understand.

I have this code:

```html
<div> text 1 </div>
<div> text 2 </div>
<button> invert </button>
```

Comment: What javascript do you have so far?

Comment: *You* want to "create a function"? Or you want *someone else* to "create a function"?

Comment: Well, I know the code doesn't include javascript, that's why I want to create a javascript function. That is the only code I have. I tried with reverse, but it doesn't seem to be working

Comment: Wes, I just want a hint, I didn't ask for someone to create it. As I said, I;m trying to learn. I've done a few functions, but this one kinda bugs me.

Comment: Thank you all for your answers. I will try every example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using pure javascript, you can simply switch the contents of each div:

```js
function flip(){
  div1_content = document.getElementById("div1").innerHTML;
  div2_content = document.getElementById("div2").innerHTML;
  
  document.getElementById("div1").innerHTML = div2_content;
  document.getElementById("div2").innerHTML = div1_content;
}
```

```html
<div id="div1"> Text 1 </div>
<div id="div2"> Text 2 </div>
<button onclick="flip()"> Flip it! </button>
```

We're simply storying the contents of each div, then assigning them to one another. Hopefully, you can take this, learn from it, and apply it how you intend to.

Comment: Thank you very much. I will.

Comment: No problem. Be sure to accept the answer if it helped!

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple javascript solution

jsFiddle https://jsfiddle.net/xzLme043/2/

```
myFunction = function(){
    var div1 = document.getElementById('one');
    var div2 = document.getElementById('two');

    var html = div1.innerHTML;
    div1.innerHTML = div2.innerHTML;
    div2.innerHTML = html;
};
```

Comment: This is jQuery. He's looking for javascript

Comment: Much shorter & faster as it does not query the DOM twice.

Comment: @GoneCoding Does jQuery query the DOM every single time you use a selector? It doesn't try to reduce it in any way?

Comment: @Abdul: Cache selector results to a local variable in jQuery. It does not cache it internally. ID lookups are lightning fast, but you still don't want the parsing overhead in a processor intensive operation.

Answer (score 1):

For this solution, you'll just place the current two divs in another parent div container, and then just insert the second div before the first, on the click of the invert button. No changing or pulling of inner text or HTML required.

```js
function invertDivs(parentDiv) {
  var first = document.getElementById(parentDiv).firstElementChild;
  console.log(first);
  var second = document.getElementById(parentDiv).lastElementChild;
  console.log(second);
  document.getElementById(parentDiv).insertBefore(second, first);
}
```

```html
<div id="parent">
  <div id="first">div 1</div>
  <div id="second">div 2</div>
</div>
<button onclick="invertDivs('parent');">invert</button>
```

Comment: Thank you. I will try this example as well.