# JavaScript insertBefore not working properly

Tags: javascript, html, css

In an attempt to make my answer more flexible on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31682032/flip-divs-using-a-function) question:

```js
function invertDivs(parentDiv) {
  var first = document.getElementById(parentDiv).firstChild;
  console.log(first);
  var second = document.getElementById(parentDiv).lastChild;
  console.log(second);
  document.getElementById(parentDiv).insertBefore(second, first);
}
```

```html
<div id="parent">
  <div id="first">Div 1</div>
  <div id="second">Div 2</div>
</div>
<button onclick="invertDivs('parent');">Invert Divs</button>
```

However, the divs are only inverted sometimes, not always.

An initial click on the button yields this on the console:

[image]

A second click:

[image]

After a bunch of clicks:

[image]

I'm confused as to what's wrong with the code. I select the first child of parent div, and do the same for the last child. Then I just insert the current second div before the first. That's the end of the function. They are also the direct children of the parent div, as required by the `insertBefore` function.

Comment: Keep in mind that text nodes are also child nodes. I guess you want to use [`firstElementChild`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ParentNode/firstElementChild) instead, or `childNodes[0]`.

Comment: Each of the white spaces in your `HTML` will be considered as a `text node`. You might not run into the issue when you get rid of all the spaces in your HTML. But that is a pain. Instead you need to check for the `nodeValue` . `1` is an element node and `3` being the text node. So you need to add additional checks in place to avoid processing the `1's`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As mentioned in comments, `firstChild` and `lastChild` can return text nodes for the whitespace between elements. You can use `firstElementChild` and `lastElementChild` to ignore these.

```js
function invertDivs(parentDiv) {
  var first = document.getElementById(parentDiv).firstElementChild;
  console.log(first);
  var second = document.getElementById(parentDiv).lastElementChild;
  console.log(second);
  document.getElementById(parentDiv).insertBefore(second, first);
}
```

```html
<div id="parent">
  <div id="first">Div 1</div>
  <div id="second">Div 2</div>
</div>
<button onclick="invertDivs('parent');">Invert Divs</button>
```

For some other workarounds, which you might need for older browsers, see [element.firstChild is returning '<TextNode ...' instead of an Object in FF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2299807/element-firstchild-is-returning-textnode-instead-of-an-object-in-ff)

Comment: Didn't even know these element variants were added - seems I need to brush up on the DOM.

Comment: @Barmar is `firstElementChild` essentially `parent.children[0]` under the hood?

Comment: @Abdul It looks like it is.

Comment: @Abdul no, both `parent.children[0]` as `parent.childNodes[0]` behave like `parent.firstChild`. Seems like the only methods that accurately find only child elements are indeed `firstElementChild` and `lastElementChild`. All the others find all and every kinds of elements, including spaces and line breaks. Take a look at [W3C's reference](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_element_lastelementchild.asp).

Answer (score 3):

You're not taking into account text nodes. In your HTML example above, there are 5 nodes.

```
[0] => TextNode
[1] => #first
[2] => TextNode
[3] => #second
[4] => TextNode
```

It seems pretty evident that you don't care about the text nodes here. You have quite a few options.

One option would be to filter out all the text nodes. (Can't use Array.prototype.filter method because childNodes is not an array, but a NodeList)

This will give you an array of only DOM elements.

```js
function invertDivs(parentNodeId) {
  var childElements = [],
      parentNode = document.getElementById(parentNodeId);
  
  //Filter out the child nodes that aren't elements.
  //parentNode.childNodes is a NodeList, and not an array (even though it looks like one)
  for (var i = 0; i < parentNode.childNodes.length; ++i) {
    if (parentNode.childNodes[i].nodeType === 1)
      childElements.push(parentNode.childNodes[i]);
  }
  
  parentNode.insertBefore(childElements[childElements.length - 1], childElements[0]);
}
```

```html
<div id="parent">
  <div id="first">Div 1</div>
  <div id="second">Div 2</div>
</div>
<button onclick="invertDivs('parent');">Invert Divs</button>
```

Another option would be to use the more modern DOM API properties: See Barmar or GolezTrol's answers. They would be much more performant if you audience has support for IE9+ browsers.

Answer (score 1):

It's not random. If I click 2 times, to add Div 2 to the end of the list, then click 3 times to get Div 1 at the end of the list. This pattern repeats.

The reason is because there are also next nodes inbetween. This is the whitespace inbetween the elements.

To work around this, use the `children` attribute. This selects the child *elements* (instead of *nodes*).

```js
function invertDivs(parentDiv) {
  var parent = document.getElementById(parentDiv);
  var first = parent.children[0];
  console.log(first);
  var second = parent.children[parent.children.length-1];
  console.log(second);
  document.getElementById(parentDiv).insertBefore(second, first);
}
```

```html
<div id="parent">
  <div id="first">Div 1</div>
  <div id="second">Div 2</div>
</div>
<button onclick="invertDivs('parent');">Invert Divs</button>
```

Comment: is `firstElementChild` essentially `parent.children[0]` under the hood?

Comment: Yes it is, although it doesn't fail but return `null` when there is no child. So actually `firstElementChild` is easier to use. Note browser compatibility though. `firstElementChild` is available in IE9+. `children` was already available in earlier versions, although it had a small bug in IE8 and before: it also included comments... If you don't care about IE8- (and you shouldn't), then `firstElementChild` is the easiest choice.

Answer (score 1):

The answer to your question is given in the MDN docs(https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/firstChild) for Node.firstChild. If you refer to docs you will understand why you are getting the #text as the first Node.